# Can ios Bluetooth api discover android device?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I know, transferring is restricted and i do not need that. Also, i'm aware of BLE capabilities. However, ~35% of android devices out there do not support peripheral mode.

If someone ever tried this, could you tell me: does ios BT api allow to discover android devices? I need only mac (or whatever it called) address from android device, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

iOS (CoreBluetooth) can discover any Android BLE device as long as it supports the Peripheral role. If your Android device does not support Peripheral role then the iOS device needs to be the Peripheral in your connection scenario.

If you want to use Bluetooth Classic, that is a completely different story because in order to use Bluetooth Classic on iOS you need to be member of Apple's MFI program that comes with extra fees and an NDA.